# React Tooltip using Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tooltip

I have a google maps widget on my page with markers on it to represent specific locations. I have made it so that when you click on the marker, a tooltip will appear above it to show more information. I am using [react tooltip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip). Here's my `index.jsx`

```
<GoogleMaps
  bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: /* KEY */ }}
  center={center}
  zoom={zoom}
>
  <ReactTooltip
    id="google"
    html
    multiline
  />
  {markers.map((marker) => (
    <Marker
      key={marker.key}
      place={marker}
      lat={marker.lat}
      lng={marker.lng}
    />
  ))}
</GoogleMaps>
```

Here's my `Marker.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import MarkerWindow from "./MarkerWindow"

const Marker = ({ place }) => {
  const tip =
    <>
      <MarkerWindow place={place}/>
    </>;
  return (
    <>
      <Wrapper
        data-for="google"
        data-event="click focus"
        data-tip={tip}
      />
    </>
  )
};

export default Marker;
```

And then my `MarkerWindow.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const MarkerWindow = ({ place }) =>
  (
    <StyledSection>
      <h3>${place.name}</h3>
      <p>
        ${place.address}
        <br />
        ${place.number}
        <br />
      </p>
    </StyledSection>
  );

const StyledSection = styled.div`
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background-color: #e01414;
`;

MarkerWindow.propTypes = {
  place: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default MarkerWindow;
```

But when I load the page, I get this:

[image]

How do I load custom components into ReactTooltip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

react-tooltip doesn't support components as the tooltip content, but accepts html strings.

1. You should use the `data-html={true}` prop to let the react-tooltip know that the value passed to `data-tip` is actually an HTML code.
2. Then you should provide the html of the tooltip content as a `string`.

So this should work:

```
const Marker = ({ place }) => {
  const tip = `
    <div style="width: 18px; height: 18px; background-color: '#e01414';" >
      <h3>${place.name}</h3>
      <p>
        ${place.address}
        <br />
        ${place.number}
        <br />
      </p>
    </div>
  `;

  return (
    <>
      <Wrapper
        data-for="google"
        data-event="click focus"
        data-html={true}
        data-tip={tip}
      />
    </>
  )
};
```

I converted your `MarkerWindow` component to an HTML string by inlining the styles from the styled-component.

However, if you are not limmited to use react-tooltip I suggest to use other packages that let you render react components for a tooltip content. Take a look at [@tippyjs/react](https://github.com/atomiks/tippyjs-react) for example.

Comment: This makes sense. We are able to switch libraries but I tried tippyjs and unfortunately it does not seem like it is compatible with `google-map-react`. Tippsy requires the marker to be wrapped by `<Tippy>` tags but that prevents the markers from getting rendered on the map.